# How to launch default home launcher through code while working with real device?

Tags: android, default, android-launcher, android-homebutton

I have succeeded in launching the default home launcher through the following code while working with the emulator:

```
Intent de_intent=new Intent();
de_intent.setClassName("com.android.launcher","com.android.launcher2.Launcher");
startActivity(de_intent);
```

But when I am executing this code in the real device, it is showing following exception:

```
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher} have you declared this in AndroidManifest.xml
```

Can anybody help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try following:

```
 Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startMain);
```

Comment: Thank U very much for your fast and useful reply, it worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have a Samsung device? They replaced the default Android launcher with their TouchWiz Home launcher. The following code worked for me using the setClassName() method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setClassName("com.sec.android.app.launcher", "com.android.launcher2.Launcher");
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This is not an answer for this question but exactly what I need. So thanks and +1!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return to HOME, you can use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(intent);
```